# Add x-axis labels on top and bottom of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Does anyone know how to have x-axis labels appear on the top of the graph while retaining the labels on bottom. I have found plenty of posts about doing scale_x_continuous(position = "top"), but this does not retain the bottom axis. For example, with the iris dataset, I would like to create a graph similar to the following:

[Iris Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMi02.png)

Comment: `+ scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())`

Comment: Thanks Jon that worked!